# How to assign column values based on another column iteratively with Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

For these two dfs, I want to check for each i in df1["TS"] if df["TS"] == df1["TS}, then assign the value in "Dr" that corresponds to i to the "mmsi" column:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"TS": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], "mmsi":[11,12,13,14,15,16,17]})


df1 = pl.DataFrame({
"TS": [4, 6, 7], 
"Dr": [21,22,23]})
```

I want the output of df["mmsi"] to be: `[11,12,13,21,15,22,23]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a "left" [`join`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.join.html), followed by a [`fill_null`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.fill_null.html), to fill in values of `Dr` that are not found.

```py
df.join(
    df1,
    on="TS",
    how="left"
).with_column(pl.col('Dr').fill_null(pl.col('mmsi')))
```

```
shape: (7, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬─────┐
│ TS  ┆ mmsi ┆ Dr  │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 11   ┆ 11  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 12   ┆ 12  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 13   ┆ 13  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 14   ┆ 21  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ 15   ┆ 15  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6   ┆ 16   ┆ 22  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7   ┆ 17   ┆ 23  │
└─────┴──────┴─────┘
```

Your result is in the `Dr` column.  If needed, you can drop/rename columns so that `mmsi` is the final column.

```py
df = (
    df.join(df1, on="TS", how="left")
    .with_column(pl.col("Dr").fill_null(pl.col("mmsi")))
    .drop("mmsi")
    .rename({"Dr": "mmsi"})
)
print(df)
```

```
shape: (7, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ TS  ┆ mmsi │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 11   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 12   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 13   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 21   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ 15   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6   ┆ 22   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7   ┆ 23   │
└─────┴──────┘
```

Taken in steps, the "left" join will yield the following.

```py
df.join(
    df1,
    on="TS",
    how="left"
)
```

```
shape: (7, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ TS  ┆ mmsi ┆ Dr   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 11   ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 12   ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 13   ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 14   ┆ 21   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ 15   ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6   ┆ 16   ┆ 22   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7   ┆ 17   ┆ 23   │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘
```

The `fill_null` step will then fill in any missing values in the `Dr` column using the corresponding values in the `mmsi` column.

The performance of this will be much better than iterating over values using a for loop.